# Figure is placed in a wrong position

Tags: floats, positioning, sections-paragraphs, placeins

I have read many threads regarding misplaced floats in LaTex, however, I haven't found a satisfactory answer yet. As shown by the code segment, Fig 1 is supposed to be after the "In order to test ..." paragraph and before the "Using the digital ..." paragraph. However, when it is placed in some random location in between the text of the paragraphs. Any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[aps,reprint,nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
.
.
.
In order to test... 

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{1}
\caption{Circuit used to test Kirchhoff's laws.}
\end{figure}

Using the digital...
```

EDIT: I just noticed that the location at which the figure is supposed to be is too small. However, shouldn't the `placeins` package take care of this issue? Essentially what LaTex is doing is filling that otherwise empty space with the text of the next paragraph, the one which is supposed to come after the figure.

Comment: here is an answer to your question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned

Comment: I have tried all those combinations. Still the same result :(

Comment: Have you also tried using a minipage?

Comment: Yes! The mind-boggling thing is that I have been writing with the same settings for so long, and never had this issue. I can't figure out why all of a sudden this one image (I have more that are in the right spot) isn't being located properly.

Comment: Floats float. Don't put it in a `figure` environment. `placeins` with `section` will stop it floating into another section. It won't stop it floating within a section. A `figure` is designed to float. That is what it does. It is its raison d'être, its essential being, its purpose in life. You don't have to use a `figure`. If you don't want one, just don't use one.

Comment: Use `\captionof` from `caption` or `capt-of` if you need a caption.

Comment: And please always post a complete example.

Comment: I apologize for incomplete example, I thought simplicity would help. Does there exist any sort of method such as `placeins` that work within a section?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\usepackage{float}`
And then say `\begin{figure}[H]`

Comment: you saved me alot of time.